# EF Core: Exclude already written items from tracking

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I have two entities with relation many-to-many.

```
class Action
{
   public int Id {get;set;}

   public List<Case> Cases{ get; set; } = new();
} 

class Case 
{
   public int Id {get;set;}

   public string Value { get; set; }

   public List<Action> Actions { get; set; } = new();
}
```

I'm doing my business logic and collecting List Actions where each action is a new instance that will be written to DB. Meanwhile I do that, I'm defining some cases that belongs to that actions openning db context. If a case already exist in DB, I'm just linking it to an action, but if doesn't, I'm creating a new instance without writing it to DB and linking to an action.

```
var result = new List<Case>();
using (var context = new MyDBContext())
            {
                foreach (var item in cases)
                {
                    var caseFromDB = context.Cases.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == item);
                    if (caseFromDB != null)
                    {
                        result.Add(caseFromDB);
                        return result;
                    }
                    else
                        result.Add(new CaseNumber { Value = item });
                }
            }

action.Cases.AddRange(result);
```

Finnishing all calculations I'm openning new DB Context and writing all actions to DB. Getting error: "The instance of entity type 'Case' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked...."

My code is following:

```
using (var context = new MyDBContext())
            {
                foreach (var action in actions)
                {
                    context.Actionss.Add(action);
                }
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
```

I triyed to remove cases that already added to DB but I just lose the relation between records.

Please advice how to fix this issue. Thanks!

Comment: The database must have the ID as a Primary Key.  When you are a Primary Key only one row of database can contain the key.  Are you using EF 4.1 or later?  See https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/dbcontext/adding-data

Comment: Relation scheme built well and each table has PK. My issue was because of usage different DB contexts. So Steve Py provided good explanation of my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with this approach. Firstly, when dealing with related entities you should always seek to use the same DbContext instance, loading cases with one DbContext then saving actions with a different DbContext whole associated to the cases instance is not ideal because some cases will be from the DB while others are not.

However, the crux of your problem will be caused by this logic:

```
if (caseFromDB != null)
{
    result.Add(caseFromDB);
    return result;
}
else
    result.Add(new CaseNumber { Value = item });
```

Based on the fact that these cases are being added to an action and the second code example is going though and saving multiple actions, this will cause big issues where you "add" an unknown new case number to two different actions. Even calling this method reading existing cases for each action will be a problem because each action's cases will have been loaded as a separate instance by a different DbContext instance. For instance if you have 2 actions, the first action loads Case #1 and #2, and adds #3. The second action wants to load Case #1 and adds #3. What you will end up with is 2x references to Case #1 and #3 when your "Actions" DbContext goes to save the two actions. Chances are you will have other issues with trying to save an existing Case # since the Case #1 will be a detached instance this DbContext doesn't know about and it will try inserting a new row, either creating a duplicate or complaining about constraint violations. Even if dealing with just new cases (#3) The first one will succeed and the DbContext will start tracking it, but the second Action will fail because it's #3 is a different instance for the same data.

Basically ***don't*** split operations between DbContext instances. Worst case if you are not using an injected DbContext instance with a lifetime scope managed by a container, and want separate methods to handle loading/associating cases and saving actions, pass a single DbContext managed outside of these methods into these methods to use, rather than instantiating new DbContext instances everywhere. As a general rule of thumb to make your life a lot simpler with EF, an Entity should never be passed beyond the scope of the DbContext that loaded, or persisted it.

So for instance if I have a list of new Actions to save and I have a list of Cases to associate to those actions, ideally I should do this within the scope of a single DbContext, **and** ensure that new items are always dealing with the same reference.

One optimization we can make to find existing cases, is to load them in one DB query:

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext())
{
    var cases = context.Cases
        .Where(x => caseValues.Contains(x.Value))
        .ToList();
    var newCases = cases
        .Except(cases.Select(x => x.Value))
        .Select(x => new Case { Value = x })
        .ToList();
    cases.AddRange(newCases);
    
    foreach(var action in actions)
    {
        action.Cases.AddRange(cases);
        context.Actions.Add(action);
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Now this assumes that all applicable actions to be added share the same list of cases. If the cases applicable to each action are different then this would need to be adjusted somewhat. However the key differences here are that we want to deal with a single DbContext so tracking references are pointing at the same object instance for the same case value, whether loaded from the DB or created as a new entry. In this case I load all cases that I can match from the DB, then find the Values for new items by stripping out the values I found from the DB, and projecting those each to a new Case. This way for a given case Value there will only be one reference to a Case entity, whether existing or new.

Comment: Thank you so mach for advice. I changed the approach and now everithing work fine.